# Creating list of selected features using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I used the select by location tool to see where a project location intersected with multiple features (sensitive areas).

How do I create a list of the selected features based off their layer names using ArcPy?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Unfortunately, specifying multiple solution paths is, in effect, asking multiple questions, since the answers they generate all can be correct, but can't be evaluated as to which is "best".  Since you already have a Python answer, focusing this on a Python solution is probably best.

Answer (score 2):

With ArcPy and Python you can build empty lists, and then use a [SearchCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) on each layer to iterate through all the selected features and add each one to the list.

Building off the example code in the documentation linked above, something like this:

```
import arcpy

fc = 'c:/data/base.gdb/well'
fields = ['WELL_ID', 'WELL_TYPE', 'SHAPE@XY']
select_list = []

### run Select by Location on fc ###

# For each selected row, add it to the list
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        select_list.append(row)
```

Comment: GDB with feature classes (a, b, c, d, e, f) and X project locations feature class. I use the select by location tool with many input features (a, b, c, d, e, f)(sensitive areas) and selecting feature X (project location). The tool selects all input features that intersect with the X. I would like a list or excel tables of the select features. It would be nice to automate vs exporting one by one.

Comment: Then just expand on the python code. Put your Select by Location and SearchCursor code into functions that you run for each feature class in the geodatabase, and either append the selections into one giant list, or combine a bunch of individual lists together at the very end. You could export that final list to a csv. Or instead of using a search cursor to iterate through each selected feature, just export each selection's attribute table to a csv like is described in this post: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/export-selected-records-to-csv-using-python-idle/td-p/503448